# VBA Excel set variable on 2digit after the comma

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set a result with 2 digits after the comma.

Is there any fast way to do this please ?
Because I need first to look for the result.
(If positif : add "+", negatif let the "-" and null "make it on 0.00)

```
Dim VariationX as Single
VariationX = 0,5
If VariationX >= 0.01 Then
    VariationXString = "+" & VariationX 
ElseIf VariationX = 0 Then
    VariationXString = "0,00"
End If
VariationXString = Replace(VariationXString, ",", ".")
```

In this exemple
The result will be "+0.5"
But I want "+0.50" because in some case, the VariationX could be "10,50", "1,20", "-2.8" or simply "1". And I always need to have 2 digit after the comma.

Was going to use InStr, Len and Mid, but this would make a lot of line just for this.

Comment: did you try in american style: `VariationX = 0.5` and `If VariationX >= 0.01 Then`

Comment: Just did an edit because yes : `If VariationX >= 0.01` is working.
but `VariationX = 0.5` can't because for real VariationX is something like : `VariationX = Var1 - Var2`, these Var are not `as Single`. (no dim)

Comment: The idea is that vba is american style centric.  So if your numbers are coming in as `##0,##` then it is a string and it needs to be converted to `##0.##` to make work.

Comment: @ScottCraner so what "Dim" should I put on Var1 and Var2. because I got Var1 and Var2 as `##0.##` then I replace the "." by "," to make the `VariationX = Var1 - Var2` work.

Comment: They are still strings so you will need convert them to singles or doubles.  Try `Cdbl` or `Csng`

Comment: @ScottCraner That's right, Cdbl and Csng not worked. Error13.

Comment: Would a formula like =SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(ROUND(A1,2),"@"),".",",") work?

Comment: You used `variationX = CSng(var1) + CSng(var2)`?

Comment: @TonyM Nop
@ScottCraner yes, and I used this too `var1s = Csng(var1)` none worked

Comment: Never `Null`. For Example :
`Var1 = "4,90"
Var2 = "4,40"
VariationX = Var1 - Var2`
So VariationX = 0,50

Comment: What are the values of var1 and var2? If no numbers included then `CSng()`will fail with error 13. Go with Mats!

Comment: Had to delete comment, because `Csng(Null)`raises error 94 not 13. How did you check the values? A watch, `Debug.Print`? `Msgbox CSng("4.90") - CSng("4.40")`doesn't work?

Comment: The value is an extraction from string. It was like "Data-ok:4.80:done" Then I extract only the 4.80 into Var1 (for this I use InStr and Mid). But first I check with "if" if it's null, so do nothing.

Comment: @user3114471 the more you describe the *actual* problem you're solving, the more I wonder why you're not just using a regular expression to parse the string.

Comment: Lol I passed an entire day for learning to use regex. I made a function with it.

But I become really faster now with this solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to be boring, but this looks like a job for a custom number format...

Number formats are structured like so: `[positive];[negative];[zero];[text]`. So you want something like this:

```
"+"#,##0.00;"-"#,##0.00;#,##0.00
```

I get `0.00` for any zero value, `+0.50` for 0.5, and `-0.25` for -0.2463.

The *representation* of a value is different from that *value*. If you want to be able to use `0.5` in calculations, having it stored as `"+0.50"` is going to cause headaches - but having it stored as `0.5` and *represented* as `+0.50` won't break anything.

---

If the presentation concern needs to be addressed in code (e.g. if you want that formatted string value to show up in some form's `TextBox`), then you can use the `Strings.Format` function to get the same result:

```
Public Function PrettifyVarianceFigure(ByVal value As Double) As String
    PrettifyVarianceFigure = Strings.Format$(value, _
        IIf(value > 0, "+", vbNullString) & _
        "0" & Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) & "00")
End Function
```

You can convert back to /round-trip to a `Double` by using the standard conversion functions*:

```
Debug.Print CDbl(PrettifyVarianceFigure(0.42)) ' outputs 0.42
```

*I doubt `CDbl` will handle a non-dot decimal separator though, so you might need to make a `Strings.Replace` call first.

Comment: <sarcasm>blah...blah... blah, I'm Mat's Mug I fix the real question instead of spinning my wheels trying fruitlessly to fix the code. blah...blah...blah. </sarcasm> 8P

Comment: @ScottCraner I literally LOL'd =)

Comment: Yes, that's right, just for information : the result is never lower than 2 digit after the comma. So I will never encounter -0.2463 (if this can help you).

Reprensented as +0.50, my problem is because I'm making a function, and the result should be exactly like what you showed but into a variable : `"+"#,##0.00;"-"#,##0.00;#,##0.00` (it's going to be stored into a variable)

Comment: @user3114471 that's even more of a reason to use a number format - you want that value to be a `Double` in your code (or a `Single`... whatever), and only show up fancy-formatted *when it's on the worksheet*. Dump your values onto the sheet, and then set the destination range's `NumberFormat` accordingly. I only included `-0.2463` to show how it would behave in such cases.

Comment: Ok, so how can I do this please ? If I put for exemple +0.5. (+0.5 is a string)

Comment: @user3114471 I've added a function that does the same thing in VBA, and honors whatever decimal separator you've got on your system. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but sorry it doesn't worked, the result is "000" or "+001" tried to convert my variationX to single or double, and you function the value as double or single too.

Comment: Hard-code a dot then (`PrettifyVarianceFigure = Strings.Format$(value, IIf(value > 0, "+", vbNullString) & "0.00")`), this code works as-is and perfectly fine on my machine. What's your decimal separator anyway?

Comment: Some test done, and it's lookslike it work really good. Thanks you a lot !